# How to set the page title when sending a file to the browser using Response.OutputStream.Write

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, http-headers, content-disposition

I have a page that I use to pull a file from the database and either prompt for download or stream to the browser depending on how the URL is formatted.  This is working fine, however nothing I do will work when trying to set the page title and it defaults to the domain name in the URL.

I realize this is most likely happening because I am sending a binary file to the browser using `Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)` and so according to something else I found online "I am filling up the buffer with the binary file so I have no control over the title"

> You are filling up the buffer with a binary file, with no HTML and hence no Title Tag. I am not sure you have any control over the Title tag in the browser at this point. Let me check on a page I have up right now with a PDF. It does not look like this can be done, at least in the example I am looking at. I had another PDF opened, but it was to a local file directly and it had the Title tag set in the browser. I am not sure if this was embedded in the PDF or not.

Found here: http://forums.asp.net/t/1088814.aspx/1

I have tried all the normal places to set the page title:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="FileServer.aspx.vb" Inherits="FileServer" Title="Title goes here" %>
```

or

```
<head runat="server">
    <title>Title goes here</title>
</head>
```

or

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim FileNumber As String = RouteData.Values("FileNumber")
        Dim Disposition As String = RouteData.Values("Disposition")

        If FileNumber IsNot Nothing Then
            Title = "Title goes here"
            ServeFile(FileNumber, Disposition)
        End If
End Sub
```

Is there any way for me to set this title or am I out of luck?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot set the title while at the same time sending a file down to the browser.  For the browser to change the "page" title, it needs to actually render an HTML document (ie. it needs to render a page).

In this situation you're not sending any valid HTML content, hence the fact that the contents you are sending are downloaded.

If you want to do this, what you will need to do is do a sort of "bounce".  Redirect to a page that renders out the title, and any other content that you want (ie. an aspx page).  And from that page "bounce" the browser over to the download.

Comment: I had thought about that and wondered if it would keep the title when doing the redirect.  I also just found somewhere else that someone suggests the only way to do it would be to send the contents of the file into an iframe.  Neither one great options, but I think you just confirmed what I was afraid of - thanks :)

Comment: It should keep whatever content was there before the redirect, again because it has no other content to render inside the browser.  You could do something with an `iframe`, but personally I think `iframe`s are evil so I avoid them like the plague.

Comment: It looks like the `iframe` may be my only option.  I tried a `Response.Redirect` and it overwrote my title and everything else in the page.  I think this would work if I was sending it as a download, but since I am streaming the file to the browser it is overwriting everything in the browser already.  Now to decide if I really need the title enough to use the iframe...

Comment: Try using `Server.Transfer` instead.

Comment: I tried that as well and couldn't get it to function correctly given the fact that my URL is using Routing and not the standard URL containing an aspx file.  I am not sure what the issue is other than maybe Routing.  I did a little hardcoding and that did seem to work fine and the title stays.  So, to use this option, which I think is the best by the way, I will have to re-write my main page to use querystrings instead of Routing.

Comment: Finally I am having to scrap the whole thing.  While it worked, it only worked occasionally and was very inconsistent.  Most of the time it would overwrite the title so I cannot rely on it. Thanks for your ideas!